# How to optimize nginx for only proxy pass and ip2 location module

Tags: nginx

I am using nginx for two purpose, first is to proxy pass the request and second is to use ip2 location module. Now i want to optimize nginx to fulfill my purpose only. The problem is that, when i am using nginx for these reasons my throughput per sec decreases to near about half. Any suggetion will be appriciated, and thanks in advance.

```
content of nginx.conf

user nginx nginx;
worker_processes  2;
worker_rlimit_nofile 30000;
#worker_rlimit_nofile 200000;
worker_cpu_affinity 0001 0010;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log crit;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections 2048;
}

http {
    upstream default {
        server 127.0.0.1:8000;
    }       
    proxy_cache_path  /var/cache/nginx levels=1:2 keys_zone=one:8m max_size=3000m inactive=600m;

    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    real_ip_header X-Forwarded-For;
    set_real_ip_from 0.0.0.0/0;

    ip2location on;
    ip2location_database /data/geo/ip2location/DATA.BIN;
    ip2location_access_type shared_memory;
    include        /etc/nginx/conf-other/timezone.conf;
    include        /etc/nginx/conf-other/timezone-offset.conf;

    variables_hash_max_size 2048;
    variables_hash_bucket_size 512;

    proxy_headers_hash_max_size 2048;
    proxy_headers_hash_bucket_size 512;

    types_hash_bucket_size         512;
    server_names_hash_bucket_size  512;
    server_names_hash_max_size    8192;


    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for" "$proxy_add_x_forwarded_for" "$scheme"';

    access_log /dev/null;
    server_tokens off;
    sendfile       on;
    tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;
    keepalive_requests 100000;
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    gzip             on;
    gzip_comp_level  6;
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_min_length  1000;
    gzip_proxied     expired no-cache no-store private auth;
    gzip_types       text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
    gzip_buffers 16 8k;

    client_body_buffer_size 10K;
    client_header_buffer_size 1k;
    client_max_body_size 8m;
    large_client_header_buffers 2 1k;
    client_body_timeout 12;
    client_header_timeout 12;
    send_timeout 10;
}

content of /cong.d/virtual.conf 

server {
    listen 80;  
    server_name localhost;

    #access_log off; //Uncommit for Production

    more_set_headers 'Server: rey-dmp.com';
    error_page  404              /404.html;
    location = /404.html {
        root   /var/www/default;
    }

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /var/www/default;
    }
    location = /index.html {
        root   /var/www/default;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico {
        expires 365d;
        proxy_cache_key $uri;
        root   /var/www/public/images;
    }
    location /images/ {
            #autoindex on;
            expires 1d;

            proxy_cache_key $uri;
            root   /var/www/public;
            try_files $uri /images/default.gif;
    }

    location /js/ {
            #autoindex on;
            expires 1d;
            proxy_cache_key $uri;
            root   /var/www/dmp/public/javascripts;
            try_files $uri /images/default.gif;
    }

    location / {

        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:XXXX/;
        proxy_pass_header Server;
        proxy_redirect    off;
        proxy_set_header  REMOTE_ADDR  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   Host             $host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Scheme $scheme;
        proxy_hide_header  X-Powered-By;
        proxy_set_header   X-Referer    $http_referer;

        proxy_set_header IP2LOCATION_COUNTRY_LONG $ip2location_country_long;
        proxy_set_header IP2LOCATION_REGION $ip2location_region;
        proxy_set_header IP2LOCATION_CITY $ip2location_city;

    }
}
```

Comment: Please include more information, config, etc,. to help us understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: i have added all related info in my question.

Comment: Have you tried doing a benchmark to the proxied server directly? My guess is the proxied server is slow. You can also benchmark the non-proxy request such as the favicon.ico.